# iphone: copy or move file from document directory folder

Tags: iphone, ios

Here is my code.

```
NSArray *pathSong = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *toPath = [[pathSong objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Songs"];
    NSString *fromPath=[[pathSong objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc"];
    NSString *strdestination = [fromPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sg.mp3"];
    NSError *Error;
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:strdestination]){
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:strdestination toPath:toPath error:&Error]==NO){
            UIAlertView *Alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"copy" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Error] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [Alert show];
        }
        else{
            UIAlertView *Alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Not copy" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Error] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [Alert show];
        }
    }
```

I am getting the error logo :

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDominCode=516 "The operation couldn't be
>   completed .(Cocoa arrow 516.)" userInfo=0x681abf0
>
> NSUnderlyingError =0x681b920 "The operation couldn't be completed
>   .File exists"

abc folder  there is no song name "sg.mp3" but I'm still getting the file exists error. I don't know where I did mistake?

Comment: could you set code tag on your code in question?

Comment: You are trying to copy one file over another?

Comment: @ FaddishWorm:i want to copy one file to another folder.

Comment: @Jonathan Plackett:if you delete the source file before copying, it will show the error no such file and error code 260

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is two issues in your code:

1. You need to remove the file if it is already there
2. You need to specify a name for the destination file, means if you use like:

`NSString *toPath = [[pathSong objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Songs"];`

and

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:strdestination toPath:toPath error:&Error];
```

Then if copy occurs, it will copy the Sg.mp3 file as Songs without any type.

So you need to write it like:

```
NSArray *pathSong = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *tempPath = [[pathSong objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Songs"];
NSString *toPath = [tempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFileName.mp3"];
NSString *fromPath = [[pathSong objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc"];
NSString *strdestination = [fromPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sg.mp3"];
NSError *Error = nil;

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:strdestination])
{

  if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:strdestination toPath:toPath error:&Error]==NO)
   {
       UIAlertView *Alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"copy" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Error] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [Alert show];
   }
   else
   {
      [fileManager removeItemAtPath:strdestination error:NULL];
       UIAlertView *Alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Not copy" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Error] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [Alert show];
   }
}
```

This code will remove the file if exist at destination and then copy  the `sg.mp3` from `abc` folder to `Songs` folder with the name `yourFileName.mp3`

Comment: have to create directories manually before start copying..
Code is mentioned in the answer given below.

Answer (score 3):

Drawing upon the Midhun MP answer, here's a helper

```
BOOL moveFile(NSString *srcPath, NSString *dstPath)
{
    NSLog(@"moving %@ -> %@", srcPath, dstPath);

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:dstPath])
    {
        // in my usecase this is a hard error, bolt to prevent overwriting
        return NO;
    }

    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:srcPath])
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *destDir = [dstPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
        [fm createDirectoryAtPath:destDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dstPath error:&error]==NO)
        {
            NSLog(@"failure declassing %@", srcPath);
            return NO;
        }
        else
        {
            [fm removeItemAtPath:srcPath error:NULL]; // gr8t success
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are trying to overwrite a file with your copy.

Check your permission mask, try using the cache instead of the documents directory.

Do you mean `if(!fileExistsAtPath)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the file that's already there:

```
NSArray *pathSong = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *toPath = [[pathSong objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Songs"];
NSString *fromPath=[[pathSong objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc"];
NSString *strdestination = [fromPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sg.mp3"];
NSError *Error;


//DELETE THE FILE AT THE LOCATION YOU'RE COPYING TO
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:strdestination error:NULL];


if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:strdestination toPath:toPath error:&Error]==NO){
        UIAlertView *Alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"copy" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Error] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [Alert show];
    }
else{
        UIAlertView *Alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Not copy" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Error] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [Alert show];
    }
```