# Move Photos to other folder ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to move photos from one folder to another folder in iphone?

I have fetched all photos from camera roll. Now, i want some of them to move to some specific folder in iphone. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, sort of. As in you can access the user media library and you can copy them to you apps sandbox environment. Since iOS has no public filesystem you will not be able to copy/move them directly to some directory.

The images in the user media librarycan accessed with the [AssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=AssetsLibrary).

You can add new groups to the user media library and add picture to this group. But you can not **move**, **delete** or **replace** existing images in the user media library.

Comment: so you mean i cannot cut an image form camera roll and paste it to some other folder, right?

Comment: No you can not, you can only copy the image.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can Move All files to Under Documents folder or Caches Folder.
2. You Can Create Folder Programatically in iPhone Photos.

Please check the below Link for Reference:

[iphone: copy or move file from document directory folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005104/iphone-copy-or-move-file-from-document-directory-folder)

Answer (score 0):

here is some (untested) code for copying the thumbnail & full size version of a photo called 'name' from the shared camera roll to the documents directory in your app's sandbox:

```
        NSString *newNameThumb = @"newThumbName.png";
        NSString *newName = @"newFullsizeName.png";
        NSString *name = @"nameOfSharedPhotoToMove.png";

        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        // Enumerate just the photos and videos group by using ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos.
        [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

            // Within the group enumeration block, filter to enumerate just photos.
            [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

            // Chooses the photo at the last index
            [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {
                // The end of the enumeration is signaled by asset == nil.
                if (alAsset) {
                    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];

                    if([representation.filename isEqualToString:name]){
                        UIImage *latestPhoto =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[alAsset thumbnail]];
                        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(latestPhoto);
                        UIImage *latestFullPhoto = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullScreenImage]];
                        NSData *imageFullData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(latestFullPhoto);

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
                            NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                            NSString* newThumbPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:newNameThumb];
                            [imageData writeToFile:newThumbPath atomically:YES];

                            NSString* newFullPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:newName];
                            [imageFullData writeToFile:newFullPath atomically:YES];

                            *stop = YES; *innerStop = YES;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }];
        } failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
            // Typically you should handle an error more gracefully than this.
            NSLog(@"No photos found or permission denied");
        }];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSURL *oldDir = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/tmp/mynewdir"];
NSURL *newDir = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/tmp/mynewdir2"];

[filemgr moveItemAtURL: oldDir toURL: newDir error: nil];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: he is mentioning the camera roll, so this dosnt work as the items are not in your sandbox