# Recorded Audio file doesn't Move?

Tags: ios

I have recorded voice file store in temp directory with .m4a format I want move that directory in Document Directory.

```
but I can not Move it I got error.
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x7b660190 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=file:///Users/vinodjadhav/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/067A2EAC-9987-4861-8746-97117DCE72F2/data/Containers/Data/Application/5744F8BC-4256-4010-8A14-60B228859F88/tmp/14-11-201410:32:45.m4a, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Move
), NSFilePath=file:///Users/vinodjadhav/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/067A2EAC-9987-4861-8746-97117DCE72F2/data/Containers/Data/Application/5744F8BC-4256-4010-8A14-60B228859F88/tmp/14-11-201410:32:45.m4a, NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/vinodjadhav/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/067A2EAC-9987-4861-8746-97117DCE72F2/data/Containers/Data/Application/5744F8BC-4256-4010-8A14-60B228859F88/Documents/XpenseTag/Xpenses/sagar/823564440/audio/audio.m4a, NSUnderlyingError=0x7b660250 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

**this my dest url**

```
Dest url = /Users/vinodjadhav/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/067A2EAC-9987-4861-8746-97117DCE72F2/data/Containers/Data/Application/5744F8BC-4256-4010-8A14-60B228859F88/Documents/XpenseTag/Xpenses/sagar/823564440/audio/audio.m4a
```

**this my source file url**

source url = file:///Users/vinodjadhav/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/067A2EAC-9987-4861-8746-97117DCE72F2/data/Containers/Data/Application/5744F8BC-4256-4010-8A14-60B228859F88/tmp/14-11-201410:32:45.m4a

```
 -(void)moveAudioFileFromeSource:(NSString *)sourceUrl toDest:(NSString *)destUrl
  {
    NSLog(@"source url = %@", sourceUrl);
    NSError *Error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:sourceUrl toPath:destUrl   
         error:&Error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not remove old files. Error:%@",Error);
    }


  }
```

where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can copy the file from source path to your destination path . try like this

```
 -(void)moveAudioFileFromeSource:(NSString *)sourceUrl toDest:(NSString *)destUrl
  {
    NSLog(@"source url = %@", sourceUrl);
    NSError *Error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourceUrl toPath:destUrl   
         error:&Error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not remove old files. Error:%@",Error);
    }


  }
```

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005104/iphone-copy-or-move-file-from-document-directory-folder

Comment: I think Source url is not correct I mean this url contains file://

Comment: Yes I got error I am taking wrong Source URL it Contains file://

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64919/discussion-between-sport-and-vinod-jadhav).